# Referencing web services on test and live servers from .Net application

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, web-services

I have a .net web application which has a reference to a web service.

I published the web service to http://myTestServer/service1.asmx and then added a reference to the .net application.

The web service accesses a test datebase which is on myTestServer.

When I want to publish the web application to myLiveServer - having already published a version of my webservice that accesses 'the live database' to http://myLiveServer/service1.asmx - how can I change it so the web application references the correct web service - depending on whether I am publishing to the test, or live, server?

For things like connection strings it is easy to change a key in  to reference the right server/database. But how do you do this for a web service reference?

Comment: You shouldn't use ASMX, you should use the new WCF... ASMX has been deprecated and recommended for no future development. This is assuming you are making a new web service now and not modifying an existing ancient web service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You change it the same way you would connection strings -- that is, in the web.config, or programmatically if you prefer.  In the web.config the address sits under system.serviceModel/client/endpoint.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="service URL" name="MyService" />
    ...
```

Programmatically, you can modify your client proxy class' Endpoint.Address property.

```
var client = new ServiceReference.MyServiceSoapClient();
client.Endpoint.Address = new EndpointAddress("service URL");
```